# When will Completable Future releases thread back to thread pool?

Tags: java, java-8, threadpool, completable-future

When will `CompletableFuture` releases thread back to `ThreadPool` ? Is it after calling `get()` method or after the associated task is completed?

Answer (score 6):

There is no relationship between a `get` call and a thread from a pool. There isn’t even a relationship between the future’s completion and a thread.

A `CompletableFuture` can be completed from *anywhere*, e.g. by calling `complete` on it. When you use one of the convenience methods to schedule a task to an executor that will eventually *attempt to complete* it, then the thread will be used up to that point, when the completion attempt is made, regardless of whether the future is already completed or not.

For example,

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "hello");
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = new CompletableFuture<>();

ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> {
    try {
        f.complete("hello");
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        f.completeExceptionally(t);
    }
});
```

It should be obvious that neither, the thread pool nor the scheduled action care for whether someone invokes `get()` or `join()` on the future or not.

Even when you complete the future earlier, e.g. via `complete("some other string")` or via `cancel(…)`, it has no effect on the ongoing computation, as there is no reference from the future to the job. As [the documentation of `cancel` states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-):

> Parameters:
>
> mayInterruptIfRunning - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

Given the explanation above, it should be clear why.

There is a difference when you create a dependency chain, e.g. via `b = a.thenApply(function)`. The job which will evaluate the `function` will not get submitted before `a` completed. By the time `a` completed, the completion status of `b` will be rechecked before the evaluation of `function` starts. If `b` has been completed at that time, the evaluation might get skipped.

```
CompletableFuture<String> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    return "foo";
});
CompletableFuture<String> b = a.thenApplyAsync(string -> {
    System.out.println("starting to evaluate "+string);
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));
    System.out.println("finishing to evaluate "+string);
    return string.toUpperCase();
});
b.complete("faster");
System.out.println(b.join());
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

will just print

```
faster
```

But once the evaluation started, it can’t be stopped, so

```
CompletableFuture<String> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    return "foo";
});
CompletableFuture<String> b = a.thenApplyAsync(string -> {
    System.out.println("starting to evaluate "+string);
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));
    System.out.println("finishing to evaluate "+string);
    return string.toUpperCase();
});
LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2));
b.complete("faster");
System.out.println(b.join());
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

will print

```
starting to evaluate foo
faster
finishing to evaluate foo
```

showing that even by the time you successfully retrieved the value from the earlier completed future, there might be a still running background computation that will attempt to complete the future. But subsequent completion attempts will just be ignored.